# SVG Замена стилей для клонов объекта находящегося в symbol?

Tags: html, css, css3, svg

Есть такая задача => Дана некая svg картинка, предположим кот, которая прорисована в разных цветовых оттенках (имеет разные размеры масштабирования, положения на холсте и т.д..)
Возможно ли как-то через `css` переназначить цвет для других частей повторяющегося элемента?
 Приведу пример

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000;
}

#preloader_cats {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 60vh;
  height: 60vh;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}

.cat_body {
  fill: #ea8023
}

.cat_body:nth-of-type(2) {
  fill: #ff0
}
```

```html
<svg id="preloader_cats" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 450 450">

    <symbol id="cat">
    <path class="cat_body" d="M342 66.9c-2 1.3-3.8 2.8-6 2-55.9-19.4-42.3 11-39.7 28.5.8 5.1-.5 4.1-14.4.4-23.8-6.3-35.4-.9-25.1 43.9-24.1 43.9-25.1 53.4-33.6 80.7 119-26.2 284.6 144.9 284.9 145.1 22.2-43.5 34.8-92.9 34.8-145.1 0-73.7-24.9-141.5-66.8-195.6-12.6.4-26.2 1.4-41 3.3-30.3 3.2-81.2 29.3-93.1 36.8z"
              fill="#ea8023"></path>
              
        <g id="Cat_x5F_eyes">
        <ellipse transform="matrix(1 -.0059 .0059 1 -.856 1.716)" fill="#fff" cx="290.9" cy="146" rx="17" ry="17"></ellipse>
        <ellipse transform="matrix(1 -.0059 .0059 1 -.67 1.973)" fill="#fff" cx="334.6" cy="114.7" rx="17" ry="17"></ellipse>
        <ellipse transform="matrix(1 -.0059 .0059 1 -.834 1.722)" class="main_color" cx="291.9" cy="142.5" rx="7.6" ry="7.6"></ellipse>
        <ellipse transform="matrix(1 -.0059 .0059 1 -.648 1.979)" class="main_color" cx="335.6" cy="111" rx="7.6" ry="7.6"></ellipse>
    </g>      
    </symbol>

    <use xlink:href="#cat" x="0" y="0"/>
    <use xlink:href="#cat" id="cat2" x="100" y="35" transform-origin="50% 50%" transform="translate(-225 -20) rotate(45) "/>
</svg>
```

Можно ли как-то переназначить "цвет тела" второму, третьему и тд коту, а так же цвет глаз если помещать это всё в ОДИН тег символ (ну или другой элемент)? Вопрос больше про минимизацию кода, поскольку я понимаю что можно каждую часть повторяемых элементов завернуть в символы и уже их менять

Comment: очень интересный, а главное полезный вопрос по одной из проблемных тем SVG

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При использовании команды `<use>` элемент svg попадает в "теневой дом". Поэтому обычные приемы стилизации не работают. Так как при каждом вызове иконки это одна и та же копия одного элемента и свойства `fill` не наследуется.

**Решением данной проблемы является [использование переменных CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables).**

Мы будем использовать атрибут fill для каждой части `<symbol>` в определении нашей SVG-иконки кота и зададим им разные CSS-переменные. Затем мы назначим им разные цвета.

`.cat-colors {
  --color-0: #ea8023;
  --color-1: black;
  --color-2: green;
  --color-3: yellowgreen;
  --color-4: dodgerblue;
}`

Для второй копии кота назначаем второй цветовой набор частей тела:

```
.cat-colors2 {
  --color-0: #4D4B4B;
  --color-1: dodgerblue;
  --color-2: gold;
  --color-3: #ea8023;
  --color-4: greenyellow;
}
```

При таком использовании css переменных, допускается сколько угодно цветовых схем клонов кота. Масштабирование, перемещение не будет влиять на окраску, так как она применяется после вызова клона и всех трансформаций.

*Ниже, немного измененный код автора вопроса с добавлением CSS переменных.*

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

#preloader_cats {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 60vh;
  height: 60vh;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}



.cat-colors {
  --color-0: #ea8023;
  --color-1: black;
  --color-2: green;
  --color-3: yellowgreen;
  --color-4: dodgerblue;
} 

.cat-colors2 {
  --color-0: #4D4B4B;
  --color-1: dodgerblue;
  --color-2: gold;
  --color-3: #ea8023;
  --color-4: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<svg id="preloader_cats" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 450 450">

    <symbol id="cat">
    <path class="cat_body" fill="var(--color-0)" d="M342 66.9c-2 1.3-3.8 2.8-6 2-55.9-19.4-42.3 11-39.7 28.5.8 5.1-.5 4.1-14.4.4-23.8-6.3-35.4-.9-25.1 43.9-24.1 43.9-25.1 53.4-33.6 80.7 119-26.2 284.6 144.9 284.9 145.1 22.2-43.5 34.8-92.9 34.8-145.1 0-73.7-24.9-141.5-66.8-195.6-12.6.4-26.2 1.4-41 3.3-30.3 3.2-81.2 29.3-93.1 36.8z">
 </path>
              
        <g id="Cat_x5F_eyes">
        <ellipse id="left_Eye" transform="matrix(1 -.0059 .0059 1 -.856 1.716)" fill="var(--color-1)" cx="290.9" cy="146" rx="17" ry="17"></ellipse>
  
        <ellipse id="right_Eye" transform="matrix(1 -.0059 .0059 1 -.67 1.973)" fill="var(--color-1)" cx="334.6" cy="114.7" rx="17" ry="17"></ellipse>
  
        <ellipse id="left_pupil"  transform="matrix(1 -.0059 .0059 1 -.834 1.722)" fill="var(--color-3)"  cx="291.9" cy="142.5" rx="7.6" ry="7.6"></ellipse>
  
        <ellipse id="right_pupil"  transform="matrix(1 -.0059 .0059 1 -.648 1.979)" fill="var(--color-4)"  cx="335.6" cy="111" rx="7.6" ry="7.6"></ellipse>
    </g>      
    </symbol>
    <svg class=" cat-colors">
    <use xlink:href="#cat" x="0" y="0"  />
 </svg>
 
 <svg class=" cat-colors2">
    <use xlink:href="#cat"   x="100" y="35" transform-origin="50% 50%" transform="translate(-225 -20) rotate(45) "/> 
 </svg>
</svg>
```