# Использование CSS переменных для стилизации клонов, созданных командой <use>

Tags: html, css, css3, svg

При вызове svg элементов командой `<use>` из секции `<defs>` или из `<symbol>`

`<use xlink:href="#Martian" />`

элемент попадает в `shadow DOM`.

Для закраски svg элементов используется команда `fill="red"`, но его свойства в этом случае не наследуются. Так как мы имеем дело не с самим svg элементом, а ссылкой на него в `shadow DOM`.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
<symbol id="Martian">
<path fill="#459E48" d="M12,31c-2.3,0-3.7-3.2-4-5c0.7-1.3,3.3-2,4-2c5.7-2.4,17.8-2.9,24,0c0.7,0,3.3,0.7,4,2c-0.3,1.8-1.7,5-4,5  C33.6,32.8,14.7,34.2,12,31z"/>
<g>
 <path fill="#388E3C" d="M40,8c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,2.7-3.3,5-6,5c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1s0.4,1,1,1c3.7,0,8-3.1,8-7C41,8.4,40.6,8,40,8z"/>
 <path fill="#388E3C" d="M8,8c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1c0,2.7,3.3,5,6,5c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1s-0.4,1-1,1c-3.7,0-8-3.1-8-7C7,8.4,7.4,8,8,8z"/>
</g>
<path fill="#4CAF50" d="M12,31v-7c0-9.2,5.3-16,12-16s12,6.8,12,16v7c-1.2,5.6-7,12-12,12S13.2,36.6,12,31z"/>
<g>
 <circle fill="#8BC34A" cx="8" cy="9" r="3"/>
 <circle fill="#8BC34A" cx="40" cy="9" r="3"/>
</g>
<g>
 <ellipse fill="#FFF9C4" cx="29" cy="26" rx="2" ry="4"/>
 <ellipse fill="#FFF9C4" cx="19" cy="26" rx="2" ry="4"/>
</g>
<g>
 <circle fill="#263238" cx="29" cy="27" r="1"/>
 <circle fill="#263238" cx="19" cy="27" r="1"/>
</g>
<path fill="#173027" d="M24,33c-4,0-5.8,3-5.8,3s2.6,0,5.8,0s5.8,0,5.8,0S28,33,24,33z"/>
</symbol>  

<use xlink:href="#Martian" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Эта проблема решается принудительным наследованием с помощью правила CSS - `fill:inherit;` Но этот путь решения только для одноцветных иконок.
А как поменять цвета у многоцветных изображений, как в примере выше?

Answer (score 5):

### Решение с помощью  CSS переменных

CSS переменные наследуют свойство `fill`.  Поэтому можно внутри тега `<symbol>` назначить (объявить) переменную, значение которой, можно в последствии многократно менять для каждого экземпляра svg элемента.

```
<symbol id="predator"> 
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="transparent" />
<path id="face" fill="var(--color-face)" d="M15.4,34.1L24,37l8.6-2.9c1.9-0.6,3-2.6,2.6-4.6L33,20H15l-2.2,9.5C12.3,31.5,13.5,33.5,15.4,34.1z"/>
<path  id="nose" fill="var(--color-nose)" d="M29,30l-3-3h-4l-3,3v7c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h6c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V30z"/>
```

Каждому `path`, `circle`, `ellips`, и т.д  можно присвоить для `fill` свою переменную `fill="var(--color-face)"` и в дальнейшем менять её значение во внешней таблице стилей:

`.predator-colors {
  --color-face: #7986CB;
  --color-nose: #9FA8DA;
}`

Этот прием создаёт мощные и гибкие возможности для стилизации многоцветных иконок.

Например для одного состояния иконки мы можем назначить одну цветовую схему, а при `:hover` назначить к той же иконке другой цветовой набор.

```
.predator-colors {
  --color-face: #7986CB;
  --color-nose: #9FA8DA;
} 
.predator-colors:hover {
  --color-face: #3F8B4D;  
  --color-nose: #58C46C;
)
```

*Ниже пример, по своему вкусу легко создается и меняется цветовая схема изображения:*

```css
.predator-colors {
  --color-face: #7986CB;
  --color-nose: #9FA8DA;
  --color-hair-right:#3949AB;
  --color-hair-right2:#3949AB;
  --color-hair-left:#3949AB;
  --color-hair-left2:#3949AB;
  --color-eye-right:#1A237E;
  --color-pupil-right:#77006B;
  --color-eye-left:#1A237E;
  --color-pupil-left:#77006B;
  --color-ellipse1:#9FA8DA;
  --color-ellipse2:#7986CB;
  --color-ellipse3:#C5CAE9;
}  

.predator-colors:hover {
  --color-face: #3F8B4D;  
  --color-nose: #58C46C;
  --color-hair-right:gold;
  --color-hair-right2:#FFBB00;
  --color-hair-left:gold;
  --color-hair-left2:#FFBB00;
  --color-eye-right:#77006B;
  --color-pupil-right:#FF4151;
  --color-eye-left:#77006B;
  --color-pupil-left:#FF4151;
  --color-ellipse1:#FFDD00;
  --color-ellipse2:#C1A700;
  --color-ellipse3:#FFEE7D;
}
```

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"  width="192" height="192" viewBox="0 0 48 48" > 
<symbol id="predator"> 
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="transparent" />
<path id="face" fill="var(--color-face)" d="M15.4,34.1L24,37l8.6-2.9c1.9-0.6,3-2.6,2.6-4.6L33,20H15l-2.2,9.5C12.3,31.5,13.5,33.5,15.4,34.1z"/>
<path  id="nose" fill="var(--color-nose)" d="M29,30l-3-3h-4l-3,3v7c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h6c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V30z"/>


 <path id="hair-right" fill="var(--color-hair-right)" d="M31,7c-0.5,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,0,0,0,0,0c-0.4,0-0.8,0.2-0.9,0.6c-0.2,0.5,0,1.1,0.6,1.3   C30,10.1,40,14.4,40,32.4V37c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1s1-0.4,1-1v-4.6c0-14.4-6.1-20.7-9.5-23.1C35.9,10.3,44,14.7,44,34c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1   s1-0.4,1-1C46,7.7,31.6,7,31,7z"/>
 <path id="hair-right2" fill="var(--color-hair-right2)" d="M29.5,10.1c-0.5-0.3-1.1-0.1-1.3,0.4c-0.3,0.5-0.1,1.1,0.4,1.4c0.1,0,7.5,4.3,7.5,20.1v8c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1   s1-0.4,1-1v-8C38,14.9,29.8,10.3,29.5,10.1z"/>
 <path id="hair-left" fill="var(--color-hair-left)" d="M18.4,9.9c0.5-0.2,0.8-0.8,0.6-1.3C18.8,8.2,18.4,8,18,8c0,0,0,0,0,0c0-0.6-0.5-1-1-1C16.4,7,2,7.7,2,34   c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1s1-0.4,1-1c0-19.6,8.1-23.8,11.6-24.7C12.2,11.6,6,17.9,6,32.4V37c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1s1-0.4,1-1v-4.6   C8,14.4,18,10.1,18.4,9.9z"/>
 <path id="hair-left" fill="var(--color-hair-left2)" d="M18.5,10.1C18.2,10.3,10,14.9,10,32v8c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1s1-0.4,1-1v-8c0-15.8,7.4-20.1,7.5-20.1   c0.5-0.3,0.7-0.9,0.4-1.4C19.6,10,19,9.9,18.5,10.1z"/>

<path id="eye-right" fill="var(--color-eye-right)" d="M25,24.9c0,0,0.2,1.3,0.6,1.7s3.3,2.5,5.9-0.9c1.2-1.5,0.6-3.8,0.6-3.8S29.4,24.1,25,24.9z"/>
<circle id="pupil-right" cx="28" cy="25" r="1.5" fill="var(--color-pupil-right)" />
<path id="eye-left" fill="var(--color-eye-left)" d="M15.8,21.8c0,0-0.6,2.3,0.6,3.8c2.6,3.4,5.5,1.4,5.9,0.9c0.4-0.4,0.6-1.7,0.6-1.7  C18.6,24.1,15.8,21.8,15.8,21.8z"/> 
<circle id="pupil-left" fill="var(--color-pupil-left)" cx="20" cy="25" r="1.5" fill="red" />
<ellipse  id="ellipse1" fill="var(--color-ellipse1)" cx="24" cy="15" rx="12" ry="10"/>
<ellipse id="ellipse2" fill="var(--color-ellipse2)" cx="24" cy="13.8" rx="10" ry="7.8"/>
<ellipse id="ellipse3" fill="var(--color-ellipse3)" cx="24.2" cy="12.2" rx="8" ry="6.2"/> 

</symbol> 
 <svg class="predator-colors">
  <use  xlink:href="#predator" />
 </svg>
</svg>
```

### Ниже комбинированный пример со стилизацией трех экземпляров одного изображения.

Для каждого экземпляра созданного `<use xlink:href="#Martian" />` своя цветовая схема, которая привязывается к классу вложенного svg.

```
<div class="container">
<svg class="color-Martian">
<use xlink:href="#Martian" transform="scale(3)" />
</svg> 
 </div>
<div class="container2">
<svg class="color-Martian2">
<use xlink:href="#Martian" transform="scale(2)"  />
</svg> 
</div> 

<div class="container3">
<svg class="color-Martian3">
<use xlink:href="#Martian" transform="scale(3)"  />
</svg> 
</div>
```

**При :hover у каждого экземпляра цветовая схема заменяется на цветовую схему соседнего экземпляра.**

```css
.parent {
position:relative;
}
.container {
width:400px;
height:400px;
outline:1px solid green;

position:absolute;
top:0;
} 
.container2 {
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:150px;

} 

.container3 {
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:240px;

} 

.color-Martian {
  --color-ears: #459E48;
  --color-horn-right: #388E3C;
  --color-horn-left: #388E3C;
  --color-face:#4CAF50;
  --circle-horn-left:#8BC34A;
  --circle-horn-right:#8BC34A;
  --eye-right:#FFF9C4;
  --eye-left:#FFF9C4;
  --pupil-right:#263238;
  --pupil-left:#263238;
  --mouth:#173027;
  }  
  
  .color-Martian:hover {
  --color-ears: #504F7A;
  --color-horn-right: #504FF6;
  --color-horn-left: #504FF6;
  --color-face:#807FC4;
  --circle-horn-left:#FF00AE;
  --circle-horn-right:#FF00AE;
  --eye-right:#FFDBF4;
  --eye-left:#FFDBF4;
  --pupil-right:#263238;
  --pupil-left:#263238;
  --mouth:#FFDBF4;
  }  
  
  .color-Martian2 {
  --color-ears: #504F7A;
  --color-horn-right: #504FF6;
  --color-horn-left: #504FF6;
  --color-face:#807FC4;
  --circle-horn-left:#FF00AE;
  --circle-horn-right:#FF00AE;
  --eye-right:#FFDBF4;
  --eye-left:#FFDBF4;
  --pupil-right:#263238;
  --pupil-left:#263238;
  --mouth:#FFDBF4;
  }   
  
  .color-Martian2:hover {
  --color-ears: #770051;
  --color-horn-right: #388E3C;
  --color-horn-left: #388E3C;
  --color-face:#FFDD00;
  --circle-horn-left:#D0FF00;
  --circle-horn-right:#A0C400;
  --eye-right:#FFF9C4;
  --eye-left:#FFF9C4;
  --pupil-right:#263238;
  --pupil-left:#263238;
  --mouth:#FFF9C4;
  
  }  
  
  .color-Martian3 {
  --color-ears: #770051;
  --color-horn-right: #388E3C;
  --color-horn-left: #388E3C;
  --color-face:#FFDD00;
  --circle-horn-left:#D0FF00;
  --circle-horn-right:#A0C400;
  --eye-right:#FFF9C4;
  --eye-left:#FFF9C4;
  --pupil-right:#263238;
  --pupil-left:#263238;
  --mouth:#FFF9C4;
  } 
  
  .color-Martian3:hover {
  --color-ears: #459E48;
  --color-horn-right: #388E3C;
  --color-horn-left: #388E3C;
  --color-face:#4CAF50;
  --circle-horn-left:#8BC34A;
  --circle-horn-right:#8BC34A;
  --eye-right:#FFF9C4;
  --eye-left:#FFF9C4;
  --pupil-right:#263238;
  --pupil-left:#263238;
  --mouth:#173027;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   viewBox="0 0 48 48" > 
<symbol id="Martian">

<path id="ears"
 fill="var(--color-ears)"
  d="M12,31c-2.3,0-3.7-3.2-4-5c0.7-1.3,3.3-2,4-2c5.7-2.4,17.8-2.9,24,0c0.7,0,3.3,0.7,4,2c-0.3,1.8-1.7,5-4,5  C33.6,32.8,14.7,34.2,12,31z"/>
<g>
 <path id="horn-right"
   fill="var(--color-horn-right)" d="M40,8c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1c0,2.7-3.3,5-6,5c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1s0.4,1,1,1c3.7,0,8-3.1,8-7C41,8.4,40.6,8,40,8z"/>
 <path id="horn-left"
   fill="var(--color-horn-left)" d="M8,8c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1c0,2.7,3.3,5,6,5c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1s-0.4,1-1,1c-3.7,0-8-3.1-8-7C7,8.4,7.4,8,8,8z"/>
</g>
<path id="face"
 fill="var(--color-face)" d="M12,31v-7c0-9.2,5.3-16,12-16s12,6.8,12,16v7c-1.2,5.6-7,12-12,12S13.2,36.6,12,31z"/>
<g>
 <circle id="circle-horn-left" fill="var(--circle-horn-left)" cx="8" cy="9" r="3"/>
 <circle id="circle-horn-right" fill="var(--circle-horn-right)" cx="40" cy="9" r="3"/>
</g>
<g>
 <ellipse id="eye-right" fill="var(--eye-right)" cx="29" cy="26" rx="2" ry="4"/>
 <ellipse id="eye-left" fill="var(--eye-left)" cx="19" cy="26" rx="2" ry="4"/>
</g>
<g>
 <circle id="pupil-right" fill="var(--pupil-right)" cx="29" cy="27" r="1"/>
 <circle id="pupil-left" fill="var(--pupil-left)" cx="19" cy="27" r="1"/>
</g>
<path id="mouth" fill="var(--mouth)" d="M24,33c-4,0-5.8,3-5.8,3s2.6,0,5.8,0s5.8,0,5.8,0S28,33,24,33z"/>
</symbol> 
</svg>


<div class="container">
<svg class="color-Martian">
<use xlink:href="#Martian" transform="scale(3)" />
</svg> 
 </div>
<div class="container2">
<svg class="color-Martian2">
<use xlink:href="#Martian" transform="scale(2)"  />
</svg> 
</div> 

<div class="container3">
<svg class="color-Martian3">
<use xlink:href="#Martian" transform="scale(3)"  />
</svg> 
</div>

</div>
```

Связанный топик: [SVG Замена стилей для клонов объекта находящегося в symbol?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/864421/28748)